# Wordpress additional css is lost on theme change

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I switched themes a bit and now my additional css is lost but still gets injected into the index.php.

how can I get it back / delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are saying you added your custom CSS via "*additional CSS*" in the theme customizer. But now, when you use customizer "additional CSS" is empty but styles previously added there are still being applied.

I had a similar problem on a multi-site; I can't remember how I fixed, but, off the top of my head these are a few possible solutions:

FIRST ENSURE YOU DO NOT HAVE CACHING ENABLED

1. go to "*additional CSS*", add a single "dummy" line e.g. `.fakestyle{color:red}` and save. Hopefully this will replace the old CSS with this new line which won't affect your site. If that works, you can go back and then delete the line or just leave as is.
2. If you are using a child theme, try activating the parent theme instead and check its additional CSS/do the same there.

If the above, and any other answers fail:

3. you can try editing and removing offending styles from the database. This assumes you are familiar with MySQL or at least using phpmyadmin as you can potentially break your site. I *think* this Stackoverflow QN/answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258226/where-are-additional-css-files-stored identify the relevant entry/s.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (but i cannot be sure unless i saw the code) that the styling enacted by your themes is more **CSS Specific** than the custom styles you have implemented yourself. Here is a [specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) designed to help you solve that problem.

Try adding a `!important` flag to one of your styles and see if it makes a difference. That will confirm whether specificity is the problem.

Comment: yeah that's actually the problem, I had an ´a:hover!important´ rule in my additional css for testing. After switching themes I cant edit the the additional rule anymore, because it doesn't appear in the editor, but it's still injected into index.php, screwing up my design.

Comment: This is potentially going to be quite messy to fix - but [this article](https://css-tricks.com/methods-overriding-styles-wordpress/) looks like it might be a good starting place

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer here is that whatever is entered in the customizer "Additional CSS" field is keyed to the active theme. When you switch themes, the newly active theme has its own "Additional CSS" setting. If you switch back to the original theme, the css keyed to *that* theme shows up again.